# alert dialog on incoming call not appearing on MI Device or above 6.0

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, android-6.0-marshmallow

below is my code that i am using for displaying alert during incoming call.but the problem is it is not working on my Redmi 3s prime or any device running on 6.0.is there any permission which i have to request or any other way.any help will be more helpful.

**CallBarring.java**

```
public class CallBarring extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // This String will hold the incoming phone number
    private String number;
    CustomDialog dialog;
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    PhoneStateListener listener;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        // If, the received action is not a type of "Phone_State", ignore it
        if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
            return;

        // Else, try to do some action
        else {
            this.context = context;
            if(dialog == null){
            dialog = new CustomDialog(context);
            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            dialog.show();
            }
            // Fetch the number of incoming call
            number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    String stateString = "N/A";
                    switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        stateString = "Idle";
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        stateString = "Off Hook";
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        stateString = "Ringing";
                        dialog.show();
                        break;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(context, stateString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };

            // Register the listener with the telephony manager
            telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            // Check, whether this is a member of "Black listed" phone numbers
            // stored in the database
            /*if (MainActivity.blockList.contains(new Blacklist(number))) {
                // If yes, invoke the method
                disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
                return;
            }*/
        }
    }

    // Method to disconnect phone automatically and programmatically
    // Keep this method as it is
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private void disconnectPhoneItelephony(Context context) {
        ITelephony telephonyService;
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
            telephonyService.endCall();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

        public CustomDialog(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_item);
            Button btnEndCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end_call);
            //btnEndCall.set
            btnEndCall.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
        }
    }
```

below is my **Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="--------------"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".CallBarring" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you inplemented runtime permissions?

Comment: In MI devices sometimes they automatically don't allow some permission. You should manually allow it from their app settings i hope.Settings>Apps/Applications>Your App Please check if the permission is enabled or not. If not enable it and try. Also in 6.0 and greater devices you should implement runtime permissions

Comment: @VladMatvienko which permission i have to ask i will implement it.

Comment: any dangerous permissions. It's all on the official documentation.

Comment: @VladMatvienko also user can receive call from notification

Comment: @KarthikCP do u know which permission i have to ask.can u help please

Answer (score 0):

You could ask runtime permission as:

```
private static final int READ_PHONE_STATE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS = {
     Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
};


private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int result;
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p : PERMISSIONS) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), READ_PHONE_STATE);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case READ_PHONE_STATE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted.
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i allowed all permission manually for test  but still it is not dislplaying dialog on my device (Red mi 3s)

Comment: As i told if its 6.0 or greater runtime permission is must!